# How to implement an automatic and continuous variable load across a solar cell to obtain its I-V characteristics?

Tags: solar-cell

The project I am working on is an experimental setup to automatically characterize a solar cell. To obtain the I-V curve, the load across the cell is to be varied automatically from open circuit to short circuit. The way I am doing this is by connecting different resistors  to the cell by switching corresponding MOSFETs. The MOSFETs are turned on using Arduino. Currently, I can only have 20 different resistors, not much more than that.
The problem is that the resistance at which peak power point occurs varies with irradiance. The more the irradiance, the lower the load resistance corresponding to the peak power point decreases. When the solar cell is under a table lamp, peak power occures at 3kohm resistance. But the same occurs at under 100 ohms under daylight. As I can have only 20 sample points sufficient to construct the I-V curve and the load needs to be varied between 10kohm to 0 ohm, how can I accomplish that so that I can get sufficient samples as well as capture the peak power point? Is there any way a continuous variable load can be implemented?

Comment: Since the peak power voltage doesn't change as much as the current, it might make sense to step through fixed voltage loads rather than fixed resistance.

Comment: table lamp, daylight, do you have a lux meter?

Comment: This would be not automatic but another option is to use a potentiometer or rheostat. Actually I did it some time ago, the MCU was measuring the current and voltage at the same time. You just rotate the pot and get the curve in 30 seconds, for a given point in light conditions. I did it early in the morning, noon, cloudly, etc.

Comment: @Roland I don't have a lux meter. Under table lamp, the short-circuit current was around 2mA but under daylight, it was 47mA (I am using a 11cm X 9cm, 1W, 6V cell).

Comment: @Gos I did that too. But the requirement is to make the setup automatic.

Comment: Ok, then the solution from The Photon would be the better. With the op-amp you can drive the mosfet as a variable resistor. The ESP32 has two DAC included, with it you would regulate the resistance value programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, I can only have 20 different resistors ...

20 different resistors is way overkill, if you can select more than one at a time, give you plenty of resistance variation.

Let's say you have the following resistors, all able to be connected in parallel by their individual FET. 10, 20, 40, 80, 160 ohms ... I think you can see where this 2<sup>n</sup> sequence is going.

As they are in parallel, if you want to set the load to a resistance manually, it's probably easier  to think in terms of conductance, each resistor has half the conductance of the previous one. However, as you are already using an Arduino, let it do the sums for you! Ask it for a load resistance, it flips that to conductance, and closes the relevant FET switches to get to that total. Given the binary sequence, there is a unique set of closed switches for any given conductance, and it's trivial to select them.

Select the largest resistor for the lowest load you want to put on your cell, perhaps 100 kΩ? 20 resistors and switches will allow the smallest one to be 0.2 Ω (or is it 0.1 Ω? fence-post logic!) giving you half of that with all switches closed as the highest load.

Answer (score 3):

> As I can have only 20 sample points sufficient to construct the I-V curve and the load needs to be varied between 10kohm to 0 ohm, how can I accomplish that so that I can get sufficient samples as well as capture the peak power point?

You could select the resistor values in an (approximately) geometric series (aka on a logarithmic scale). For example use values like 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1k, 2k, 5k, 10k. That's only 13 values and will give you a reasonable look at the shape of the response curve over the range of interest. With a bit of math you could find appropriate values to fill out the sequence to 20 values if you really want to.

> Is there any way a continuous variable load can be implemented?

You could use a DAC for the control device instead of discrete FETs. That could easily give you 1000's of data points instead of just 10 or 20. It would probably be easier in this case to implement fixed current loads than resistive loads. It is possible to find current output DACs, but you'd have a lot more freedom to design your circuit  (for example to ensure it can handle the power delivered by the solar cell) if you use a voltage output DAC and an op-amp VCCS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxR2oG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's a DAC? Is there any of them that can handle 170mA or more current? can any of them handle 3A current?

Comment: @Wanderer, "Digital-to-Analog Converter". 170 mA  is conceivable but not common. 3 A is probably not available. But in the circuit I drew the DAC itself only needs to provide microamps. It's the MOSFET (M1) that needs to handle the load current.

Comment: can you give suggestions on which MOSFETs to use?

Comment: @Wanderer, if you have new questions, post them as new questions.